# Push method implementation using Stack and List ADT

Tags: java, list, stack, adt

How would I go about writing an implementation of push for the stack ADT using list ADT? Assuming i'm pushing to the top of stack, would I have to create a temp list and do something to add the previous head to the tail?

```
private someList<E> stack;

public void push(E element){
            stack.add(element);
        }



//another file
public someList<E> add(E newHead){

    return new someList<E>(newHead, this); 
}
```

Comment: Anyone?:D even a point to documentation would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is important in the implementation of the stack ADT, is where you are going to add the new elements you `push` and where you are going to delete elements you `pop`. Obviously `push(someElement); pop();` should leave the stack unchanged.

So we have 2 choices, adding/removing elements at the end of the list or in the front.

```
public void push(E element){
        stack.add(element);
}
```

You've chosen to add/remove them at the end of the list.
I don't know what the `add` method has to do, however if it returns a new `someList` which represents a/the new stack, then the private `stack` field should get this newly created stack assigned!

Note that if the purpose of `add` is to change the current head (replace current TOS (= Top Of Stack) by this one), then you could simply write it as follow

```
public someList<E> add(E newHead){
    pop(); // remove TOS
    push(newHead); // Add newHead as the new TOS
    return this.stack; 
}
```

I've implemented the `stack ADT` for `String`'s. I leave it as a simple exercise to change it to your needs (using `someList` instead of `List` and using generics).

```
public class Stack {
    private List<String> stack = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void push(String element){
        stack.add(element);
    }

    public List<String> add(String newHead){
        stack = new ArrayList<String>(stack); // you should do "stack = new someList<E>(newHead, this);"
        return stack; // return the new stack
    }

    public String pop() {
        String res = stack.get(stack.size() - 1);
        stack.remove(stack.size() - 1); // 
        return res;
    }

    public void printStack() {
        System.out.println("TOS (Top Of Stack)");
        for(int i = stack.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            System.out.println(stack.get(i));
        System.out.println("EOS (End Of Stack)");
    }
}

// Test it
...
String a = "a", b = "b";
Stack stck = new Stack();

stck.push(a);
stck.push(b);
stck.push(b);
stck.push(a);
stck.pop();

stck.printStack();
...
```

This is how the stack is changing during the test case.

```
TOS (Top Of Stack)         

a  --->   b   --->   b   --->   a   --->   b
          a          b          b          b
                     a          b          a
                                a

EOS (End Of Stack)
```

Note that in this implementation of the `stack ADT` we are pushing/popping elements from the stack by adding/removing elements from the list's tail (more precisely `arrayList`). Which is ideal for use with java's `arrayList` because adding an element to the tail of the list, or removing the last element, is in **O(1)**.

> Methods specifying insertion position have to copy all array elements to the right from insertion

[(Source)](http://java-performance.info/arraylist-performance/)

You will have to check if the same holds when using your own `someList` implementation. However, if adding an element to the tail of the list (or removing the last element) requires you to traverse the whole list (which is the case for e.g. a single linked list, hence O(n)), then adding/removing the first element should be in O(1).

In that case you should change the `stack ADT`'s implementation so that the front of `someList` is now representing the TOS and the tail of the list is representing the end of the stack. Hence push/pop will then add/remove elements at the **front** of the list.

EDIT : You could implement a `count` method :

- By explicitly remembering how many elements are on the stack (i.e. you have a `size` field that you increment for every `push()` and decrement for every **successful** `pop()` (i.e. for every `pop()` when `size > 0` then decrement `size`).
- By relying on the `size()` method of the `ArrayList` that is used to represent the stack.

Hence a possible implementation

```
public class Stack {
    private List<String> stack = new ArrayList<String>();

    ...        

    public int count() {
        return stack.size();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Well, that could work but I don't like it's *O(n)* behavior. I edited my answer in order to answer your question.