# Counting items in a Stack ADT

Tags: java, list, generics, stack, adt

Is this a good way to count items in a stack? im not sure if this is the correct method of implementation

```
private someList<E> stack;

public int countItems(){

        Stack<E> newStack = new Stack<E>();

        int count = 0;

        while(!stack.isEmpty()){

            newStack.push(this.pop());
            count++;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {  
            this.push(newStack.pop());
        }
        return count;   

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int count() {
    return stack.size();
}
```

Why posting it again?
I already answered it in your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420991/push-method-implementation-using-stack-and-list-adt/32421380#32421380) post...

The way you did it is not the way to go because of the *O(n)* behavior!
With my solution `stack.size()` it is in *O(1)* because the only thing you have to do is ask to the `ArrayList` it's size (the `ArrayList` explicitly remembers it's size so it can answer your question immediately (without having to count the elements first)).

Comment: Your absolutely right, much more efficient. Thank you for the help :)